# A/B Tests not tracking opens or clickthroughs

Tags: civimail, abtesting

I'm testing out the A/B testing feature and I'm not getting any useful information. It just reads "Tracked Opens" as "n/a" and reads zero for click throughs and unsubscribes. This is despite me opening the emails and clicking through on links.

Answer (score 1):

We are using tracking on A/B testing and it works fine, it might be something about your configuration.

Can you check on the source of the received message if
- the links you put are transformed into something else (ie. if you put google.com, it will be replaced by yoursite.org/sites/all....)
- you have an extra image with a src=yoursite.org/...

if they aren't them, you might have disabled the tracking, could check on the tab in your mailing if they are checked (track open and track clicks?)

Comment: The links do get appended with the Civi URL. I checked back this morning and the tracking info is there, it just took much longer than could be useful.

Comment: and when you click on the link, does it work properly?

Comment: Yes. The address bar flashes the tracking link and then redirects to the true destination.

Comment: Hi Tomulent. When you say the tracking info appeared eventually, what sort of delay did you/are you seeing? I did test a few hours ago and although I'm seeing data on opens I'm getting nothing yet on clickthroughs. Do I need to just be patient? Any insight into what's causing the delay?